# attempted malware infection, file with embedded link

Tags: security, malware

someone emailed me a file with an attachment of .odt text file.
when i open up the file with openoffice the text all looks similar except for one piece of it.
it sort of looks like a hyperlink, but more subtle, the color is almost the same as text.
so i still have the file, is there anyway i could use the information contained to see if i am infected?
such as using the link to find an ip address and seeing if there are connections from my computer to this ip address...
anything like that?

Comment: sorry i probably should have mentioned i originally DL'ed the file on ubuntu 10.10, but can access it from my mac osx 10.5.  no antivirus software installed, the link is a html <download> tag, btw, should i use clamxav on the linux box?

Answer (score 1):

Scan the file specifically with your antivirus (right-click and see menu example below; varies between programs) and also run it on your entire computer.

Example using [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) (highly recommend btw):

[image]